# How can I print integers in one line inside the brackets (Fibonacci sequence with nth value)

Tags: python, string, brackets

Is it possible to print integers in one line inside the brackets? I would like my output to look like this:

```
[0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34]
```

But due to the way I wrote my code I can add brackets at the end of the list `0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34[]` but not start and end.

My code:

```
n = int(input("Input a number to create Fibonacci sequence: "))

def fibo(n):
    if n <=0:
        print("Incorrect input")
        return []    
    if n == 1:
        return [0]      
    a,b = 0,1 
    for i in range(0,n):
        print(a , end = " ",)
        #assign a=b and b=a+b to get the sequence
        a,b=b,a+b    
        print()

fibo(n)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't actually print any brackets. We can't know what limitations you're working with that prevent you from printing a `[` before printing the list of numbers. Also your formatting/indentation is messed up, I recommend fixing that.

Comment: you can solve this with 2 way. 1. add a `print("[", end =' ')` before `for loop` and add `print("]")` after the `for loop` 2. create a list before `for loop` then append `a` to that list and `print` the list after the `for loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output format you are looking for is the one you get when you print a list.

You can use recursion to progressively build th eresulting list:

```
def fibo(n,a=0,b=1): return [a]+fibo(n-1,b,a+b) if n else [a]

print(fibo(10)) # fibonacci up to index 10
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

It can also be done iteratively

```
n    = 10 # first 10 fibonacci numbers
fibo = [0,1]
while len(fibo) < n: fibo.append(sum(fibo[-2:]))

print(fibo[:n])
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```